# How to make condition when image src 404 not found in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make a condition when the image src wasnt found it will display the default image

anyone can slove this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
<img style="max-height: 170px; width: 100%; border-radius: 0px !important; min-height: 170px;"
        *ngIf="obj.urlToImage != null" src={{obj.urlToImage}}
        onError="this.src='../../assets/images/defaultnews.png'">
```

Comment: use `onError` to display default image if not found